# VBA Update statement for SQL getting Error 91 Object variable or With Block

Tags: excel, vba

I have been writing a VBA update for SQL and running into the error 91. It's happening on this line `cmd_ADO.CommandText = SQLQuery`.

```vb
Private Sub Import_Click()
    Dim cn_ADO As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd_ADO As ADODB.Command

    Dim Dbconn As String

    Dim SQLQuery As String
    Dim strWhere As String

    'Dim strStatus As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim jOffset As Integer
    Dim iStartRow As Integer
    'Dim istep As Integer

    'Data Columns
    Dim strBusinessEntityID As String
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim strFirstName As String
    Dim strMiddleName As String
    Dim strLastName As String
    Dim strSuffix As String

    jOffset = 4
    iStartRow = 9
    i = iStartRow

    Dbconn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ANF-M2MCLIENT;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    Set cn_ADO = New ADODB.Connection
    cn_ADO.Open Dbconn

    While Cells(i, jOffset).Value <> ""
        strBusinessEntityID = Cells(i, 0 + jOffset).Value
        strTitle = Cells(i, 1 + jOffset).Value
        strFirstName = Cells(i, 2 + jOffset).Value
        strMiddleName = Cells(i, 3 + jOffset).Value
        strLastName = Cells(i, 4 + jOffset).Value
        strSuffix = Cells(i, 5 + jOffset).Value

        strWhere = "BusinessEntityID = " & strBusinessEntityID

        'Update Statement
         SQLQuery = "update Person.Person " & _
                    "set " & _
                    "Title = '" & strTitle & "', " & _
                    "FirstName = '" & strFirstName & "' " & _
                    "MiddleName = '" & strMiddleName & "' " & _
                    "LastName = '" & strLastName & "' " & _
                    "Suffix = '" & strSuffix & "' " & _
                    "where " & strWhere

        cmd_ADO.CommandText = SQLQuery
        cmd_ADO.ActiveConnection = cn_ADO
        cmd_ADO.Execute

        i = i + 1
    Wend

    Set cmd_ADO = Nothing
    Set cn_ADO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd_ADO` is declared but not initialized. Change the declaration line to:

```
Dim cmd_ADO As New ADODB.Command
```

Notice the addition of the `New` keyword.
See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/creating-and-executing-a-simple-command?view=sql-server-2017) for details on creating and executing a command.

---

**In addition:**
You would have errors with your SQL query string; you don't have the commas in the where you should. For example, it should be:

```
"FirstName = '" & strFirstName & "', "
```

Add the commas as you did for Title.

Comment: This fixed that error but now I'm getting an **Incorrect syntax near 'MiddleName'** and the debugger leads me to `cmd_ADO.Execute`

Comment: @David, That's a different error. You should accept and upvote this answer and and then ask a new question (or edit your original question). And the reason for that error is you don't have your commas. Look at your SQL query string. It should be `"FirstName = '" & strFirstName & "', "`. Add the commas like you did for Title.

Comment: yes, the error is fixed and the program is executing correctly

Comment: @David, it happens. Glad it worked. Now you can upvote as well. I will add that comment to the main answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialising the command object, only the connection object.

Try adding in the line:

```
Set cmd_ADO = New ADODB.Command
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91) is a link to the Microsoft documentation that explains the error in more detail.